# How to open containing folder of a file in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

This can be done in VS2017, how to in 2019? Now the only way is to open that file then right click the tab header of the opened file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131057/Use-Shortcut-or-Context-Menu-for-Open-Containing-F  - via design context menu

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidRoller.OpenFolderExtension2019 - via extenstion